# Mean Variance portfolio optimisation (Long Only) CVXPY including cardinality constraint

Tags: portfolio-optimization, python, mean-variance

I am working on a portfolio optimisation that requires me to constrain on the number of assets used, e.g from S&P500 build a 20 asset portfolio that is feasible. After doing some research I came to the conclusion that there are no non-commercial solvers freely available that can handle mixed integer and quadratic problems (I probably need SOCP as well). So I thought about a pre-optimisation step, i.e use a MIP solver to get me those 20 assets that I can then use in CVXOPT afterwards. Or any heuristic approach like genetic programming. Maybe worth mentioning that I would like to keep it as simple as possible as a first step.

My question now is, has anyone experience how this is usually implemented? Is the MIP approach a feasible one? Or can I do s.th along the lines of PCA analysis first and pick the top 20 non correlated assets.

If mixed integer programming is the way to go does anyone have a brief python example where I could get an idea how it can be implemented?

thanks

EDIT: Implementation od David's LASSO suggestion using cvxpy

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

np.random.seed(1)
n = 100

mu = np.abs(np.random.randn(n, 1))
Sigma = np.random.randn(n, n)
Sigma = Sigma.T.dot(Sigma)

w = cvx.Variable(n)
lambda_ = cvx.Parameter(sign="positive")
range_ = np.arange(0,100,1)

ret = mu.T*w
risk = cvx.quad_form(w, Sigma)

objective = cvx.Minimize(risk + lambda_*cvx.norm(w,1))
constraints = [cvx.sum_entries(w) == 1, w >= 0]
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)

weights_count = []

for lambda_vals in range_:
    print 'Lambda : ',lambda_vals 
    lambda_.value = lambda_vals

    prob.solve(verbose=False)
    print prob.status

    output = []
    for i in range(len(w.value)):
        output.append(round(w[i].value,2))

    weights_count.append(sum(1 for i in output if i > 0))

print weights_count
```

Comment: Have you taked a look a this paper and python package NCVX ?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.07277.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a <s>quick and easy</s> first step you could add $L_1$-regularization to the Markowitz problem. That is, you add a term $\lambda ||w||_1$ to the goal function of your optimization problem (where $w$ are the allocation weights to be optimized).

The $L_1$-regularization, which is often termed LASSO in the statistics community, will give you sparse solutions of the weight vectors, i.e. bring several $w_i$ down to zero and leave you with a selected number of remaining asset weights. How many assets exactly will remain depends on the choice of the regularization parameter $\lambda$, which you then should adjust accordingly in order to give 20 assets.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can stay in the same class of optimization algorithms, because the absolute value of the parameters can be incorporated by linear constraints. See for example [here](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp936.pdf?36b3daec86625a1e41e4f39905604c62).

Comment: I will definitely give this a try, what I ended up doing in the mean time was what other commercial solvers do, e.g. APT they solve for the full universe, sort be weight and truncate that list iteratively until you either reach your target universe seize or the last feasible solution. Not a big fan of that solution

Comment: Are you looking for long only solution ? 
L1 regularization will penalize short positions. Would it help to reduce cardinality in long positions ? 
Somebody is suggesting that regularizations of L^{1/2} or L^{p} might work better for long only portfolios. 

I am looking at the problem too and I was thinking of implementing something in python (but I might use NCVS to start with). Please let me know if you would be interested in doing something together.

Comment: @Bozothegrey: can you explain why L1-regularization should penalize short positions? Because imo adding the term $\lambda || w ||_1$ is from the first indifferent to the sign of $w_i$. (I mean it seems to be there as the paper also mentions it, but why? ... didn't really read the paper)

Comment: @Bozothegrey, 2: and if short positions matter, can't one introduce the (perfectly correlated) negative assets and include them all into the portfolio? (I have no clue here as I'm more of a statistics guy and haven't implemented the model yet)

Comment: @davidhigh 1. Consider the minimum variance portfolio with a full investment constraint, i.e. $\Sigma \omega  = 1$. A long only portfolio would attract a regularization cost equal to $\lambda$. Introducing a short position of weight $\hat{\omega}$ (that has to be matched by a long position by virtue of the full investment constraint), would increase the regularization cost by $2 \lambda \hat{\omega}$. So you would do that only if the quadratic term decrease at least by the same amount.  On a traditional optimization problem, a short portfolio would not attract this additional cost.

Comment: 2. I didn't get your point

Comment: Coming back to this how would you implement an iterative version of this to adjust lamdba?

Comment: Also how would you pick your initial guess, what the range for lambda

Comment: @Markuss.london: this is exactly what people do in stochastic gradient descent which is a method to solve the Lasso problem: they vary lambda from zero to large, look at the sparsity, and pick a valid result.

Comment: @davidhigh thanks David do you have any experience on performance.i.e. runtime when you have a global universe to start with with around 10k dimensions?

Comment: @Markuss.london: I've no exact timings available, but 10k dimensions worked well in my own SGD implementation (especially for larger regularization parameters $\lambda$)

Comment: @davidhigh awesome will give this a try also this is an embarrassingly parallel operation. One more question how does this effect the completeness of the cov matrix while it is running is it trimming the space with each iteration or am I always working with the full cov matrix? This seems like a perfect trade off compared to a mixed integer implementation.

Comment: @Markuss.london: optimization for different values of lambda is in fact embarrassingly parallel. However, the original authors (Friedman et al.) found that it is advantageous to reuse the already found parameters, and thus calculate multiple lambda-cases in one go. By this you loose the ability to do the calculations in parallel, but the algorithm is much faster.

Comment: @Davidhigh do you have the name of that paper

Comment: @Markuss.london: Friedman, Hastie, Tibshirani, *Regularization Paths for Generalized Linear Models via Coordinate Descent*, J Stat Softw. 2010; 33(1): 1–22.

Comment: @davidhigh I had a skim through the paper, just to make sure I understand that correctly. In my case I do my first rebalance at t0, increment $\lambda$, check results until my target size is met, then in my next rebalance at t1 I start off with my $\lambda$ from t0? I do not really get why you couldn't calculate multiple $\lambda$ in parallel here. Is there any pseudo code available? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Markuss.london: there are two dimensions here, $\lambda$ and time. The paper mentions only the first, and their finding is that calculating multiple lambdas sequentially (in a so-called regularization path) is advantageous, because you often only have small changes between adjacent lambdas, so there's no need to start again from some random initial state (in fact that's quite obvious, but it's nice: you get a whole bunch of lambdas at a moderate effort). Whether you can apply that principle to the temporal dimension as well, is your own topic -- but I would guess that it works there as well.

Comment: I will implement this using cvxpy and give it a go

Comment: @davidhigh I attached a dummy implementation in my original question, that iteratively uses $\lambda$ values 0 to 100. but it doesn't seem to effect the results I always end up with the same number of non-zero ws. I wonder if that is due to the range for $\lambda$ or my made up cov matrix.